# Is it okay to say: " ...... defines me, as me."

Tags: word-choice, american-english, syntactic-analysis, redundancy

My teacher wrote on the board: "My ability to overthink is what defines me, as me."

He asked us to correct the sentence

So my correction was, "My ability to overthink is what defines me."
I feel as though my correction is missing something. If it is missing something, what should I add-on or change or fix?

Comment: I would have simply removed the comma.

Comment: What is the context? What subject is being taught? I'm curious because as @deadrat points out, there is nothing wrong with the sentence you've been asked to correct.

Answer (score 2):

*Me, as me* means the real me; the integral, true me, as I know myself. As opposed to the persona I present to the outside world or the roles I play in other people's lives or the individual that others judge me to be.

Here's an example usage from [*Classroom Management Techniques*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ScKTo1mZidwC&pg=PR47&dq=%22me%20as%20me%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk753p-8LQAhUJJCYKHTDiCtI4HhDoAQg6MAY#v=onepage&q=%22me%20as%20me%22&f=false) by J Scrivener:

> Am I worried that students will not respect me if I let down my guard; if I let them see **me as me**, rather than as the teacher, the knower or the figure of authority?

The reason you may be uncomfortable with your answer is that you were asked to correct a sentence that had nothing wrong with it.